# Add multiple values to cookie with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I would like to store selected Id's(using Guids) into a cookie that will later be used for checkout. How do I store the new value into a cookie without overwrite the old ones?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.AddProduct').click(function () {

        //add following: $(this).data('id'), this is how far I got:
        //$.cookie("AddedProductId", $(this).data('id'));

        });
    });
</script>
```

`$(this).data('id')` gets selected Id of a product from a foreach loop:

```
<button class="AddProduct" data-ID="@item.ID">Add to Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read your cookie and then append it with new values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.AddProduct').click(function () {

    //add following: $(this).data('id'), this is how far I got:
    var previousValues = $.cookie("AddedProductId", $(this).data('id'));
    $.cookie("AddedProductId", previousValues+' ' + $(this).data('id'));

    });
});
```